# Create layout for modal window

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create overlay for modal window.
Here is my css

```
#overlay {
 position: absolute;
 background: #000;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 9800;
}
```

The problem is that layer does not cover entire page. When I scroll down overlay disappear.
What I miss ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`fixed`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) positioning:

```
position: fixed;
```

You should have:

```
#overlay {
 position: fixed;
 background: #000;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 9800;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since IE6 doesn't have support for `position: fixed` there is a solution I used in Modalbox:

```
#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    border: 0;
    background-color: #000!important;
}
#overlay[id] { position: fixed; }
```

In this case the IE will take a `position: absolute` style but every modern browser the second rule with `position: fixed`.

For IE you should use some additional CSS to prevent it from being scrollable. I managed it by setting following rules on body:

```
{
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

Better if you do it in an addition class which will be toggled on body element when you show your overlay (in JS).

Answer (score 1):

Add top:0, left:0 and position:fixed to the #overlay. U may add opacity css too .

```
#overlay {
 position: fixed;
 background-color: #000;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 9800;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 opacity:0.5;
}
```